# Oneliner pipe to PostgreSQL from MySQL with bash

Tags: mysql, bash, postgresql, pipeline

So I am piping quite a lot of data using bash everyday between 3 servers:

- Server A is mysql (connection over SSH)
- Server B is just a centos server where I run the
  bash script.
- Server C is postgresql 9.6.

All was good until one table got one row with a double quote in the middle of a varchar. This is breaking my pipe at the insertion level (on pg side).

Indeed, when getting the data this way from Mysql, it is not quoted. So, I believe in the end it's because of the basic behaviour of COPY and its QUOTE parameter.

Here is the bash code:

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -i "$SSH_KEY" "$SSH_USER"@"$SSH_IP" 'mysql -h "$MYHOST" -u "$USER"-p"$PWD" prod -e "SELECT * FROM tableA "' | \
psql -h "$DWH_IP" "$PG_DB" -c "COPY tableA FROM stdin WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'\t' NULL AS 'NULL';"
```

I tried playing with the COPY parameter QUOTE but unsuccessfully.
Should I put some sed in the middle of the pipeline?
I also tried double quoting when getting the data out of mysql but could not find the relevant parameter when mysql is used in a pipe like this.

I'd lik to keep things in one pipe (no MYSQL->CSV then CSV->PG please).#

Thanks!

Comment: just a thought: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks, I'm using fdw quite a lot. Yet and to my knowledge, none of them allow connection over ssh; or do they?

Comment: you can set up ssh tunnel, so mysql would look at localhost for postgres

Comment: @VaoTsun I haven't thought it this way, thanks! Yet, this would mean the tunnel would be there all the time, am I correct? As I have to connect to many different mysql servers for nightly jobs, that could be an issue, or am I missing something again?

Comment: well - you ssh to the target with tunnel. as long as ssh does not disconnect, you are good to use the channel.

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm lost now, sorry. Would be able to provide a short example of code please :) ?

Comment: An `ssh` tunnel isn't going to solve the problem of piping data between `msyql` and `psql`.

Comment: @chepner I suggested it for fdw

Comment: `ssh -L 3306:mysqlhost:3306 `

Comment: @VaoTsun Ok it works like a charm, thank you so much! One last thing: say my postgres DB is Redshift or any postgres version that doesn't support fdw; would would be your suggestions?

Comment: I posted example of piped import to Pg. I don't have mysql installed, but if it outputs csv to STDOUT, you can pipe it

Comment: This is exactly what I have been doing for months but the issue is that mysql does not output standard CSV (to my knowledge), hence the last comment on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working sample of importing csv to postgres:

```
t=# create table so10 (i int,t text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# \q
postgres@vao-VirtualBox:~$ echo "1,Bro" | psql -d t -c "copy so10 from stdin with csv"
COPY 1
postgres@vao-VirtualBox:~$ psql t -c "select * from so10"
 i |  t
---+-----
 1 | Bro
(1 row)
```

You can open ssh tunnel to mysql and run `mysql -h "$MYHOST" -u "$USER"-p"$PWD" prod -e "SELECT * FROM tableA "'` locally (instead of echo in my example)